# Apply a multi-variable function to a vector in R

Tags: r, function, vector, apply

I would like to define an arbitrary function of an arbitrary number of variables, for example, for 2 variables:

```
func2 <- function(time, temp) time + temp
```

I'd like to keep variable names that have a meaning in the problem (time and temperature above).

If I have a vector of values for these variables, for example in the 2-d case, c(10, 121), I'd like to apply my function (func2 here) and obtain the result. Conceptually, something like,

```
func2(c(10,121))
```

becomes

```
func2(10,121)
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish this, for an arbitrary number of variables?

Thanks

Comment: Are you coming from a language like python that supports splatting? Is it really a problem splitting up the vector when you call the function? Technically you can do this with things like `do.call` but it gets pretty messy in R. I probably wouldn't recommend it unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Can you specify it as a named vector? E.g., `func2(c(time=10, temp=121))`.

Comment: What I was trying to reproduce is something that is used in Mathematica a lot.  In Mathematica an expression like c(10,121) would have a 'Head' called List.  That head can be replaced by the name of a function with 'Apply'.  (at any level in a multidimensional array).  Answer below is useful, but my eventual goal was more complicated.  I want to produce a multi-dimensional version of 'outer'.  Like my.outer(func, a_vec, b_vec, c_vec, ..), where the function of the variables 'a', 'b', 'c', etc. would be applied to the vectors from the outer product of the vectors of values for each variable.

Comment: I wanted to use expand.grid (does require reshaping the output).  Still having a little problem.

Comment: This doesn't quite seem to work:

    apply(expand.grid(temps,times), 1, function(a) do.call(func2, as.list(a)))

although this does: do.call(func2, as.list(c(10, 121)))

Comment: @MrFlick (sorry for not including this above).  This also works:  apply(expand.grid(temps,times), 1, function(a) do.call("+", as.list(a)))

Comment: @MrFlick ... I was using temps = c(40,50,60) and times = c(1:5) for the examples above.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are getting at with these comments. Perhaps you'd be better off opening a new question so you can explain your problem more clearly. You'll likely want to stay away from `apply`

Comment: @MrFlick Agree.  It is more of a new question.  Complicated to put this into these comments, which is probably not appropriate.  Thanks again,  Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a helper function to turn a simple vector into parameters with the help of `do.call`

```
splat <- function(f,v) {
    do.call(f, as.list(v))
}

splat(func2, c(10,121))
```

Comment: Maybe return a closure to remove the need to specify `func2` at each call?

Comment: That would be a good idea as well. Just didn't want to create another variable to worry about in this example.

Comment: Thanks.  do.call and as.list will do the job.  I'd read enough to almost figure this out, but not quite.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
f = function(f,...) {
  v = list(...)
  Reduce(f, v)
}

> f(f = "+", x = pi, y = exp(1), z = pi^2)
15.72948
```

Comment: I think this is a bit different than what I was trying to do.  I think the answer above has the pieces I was missing.  Thanks.